# Turning potentiometer changes other potentiometer's value(STM32)

Tags: stm32, potentiometer

I have finished building my DIY simulator pedals for PC hacking together a 2-pedal set and adding a third.

Pressing the Gas pedal. All good [image]

Pressing the brake pedal.All good [image: https://imgur.com/YpbZ6pK]

However when pressing the clutch pedal it increases the value of the brake pedal a bit [image: https://imgur.com/E5gszod]

I they share the same ground and 3.3v and the output pins are connected to A0,A1,A7 and i am using the FreeJoy firmware to act as a HID device.

The potentiometer that i added is a 220K ohm one and the other 2 measured are about 44k(couldn't find a writing).

Here is the schematic [image]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdHhFU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am a novice in electronics(am a informatics engineer student).Any help is appreciated.

Update #1
Here is the code for the sampling rate

```
for (int i=0; i<MAX_AXIS_NUM; i++)
    { 
        if (p_dev_config->pins[i] == AXIS_ANALOG)       // Configure ADC channels
        {
            /* ADC1 regular channel configuration */ 
            ADC_RegularChannelConfig(ADC1, channel_config[i].channel, i+1, ADC_SampleTime_71Cycles5);
            axis_num++;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Alex, can you upload the images into your question. As it stands we have to follow four links to understand your question. There's a schematic button on the editor toolbar that will create a circuit using standard symbols.

Comment: Yes,of course.My bad.

Comment: What if you set longer sampling time for the higher impedance pot?

Comment: Hi,i am not using my code but FreeJoy firmware.I have added the code on the main post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One technique I've used to minimize this effect is to sample an unused channel tied to ground in between sampling the active channels.

The resistor values you are using are on the high side. I haven't specifically used that processor but on other devices, it is recommended to keep the source impedance to less than 10k ohm.

It can help if you add a capacitor to ground at each input - since the signals are very slow you could use up to 0.1uf with no problem. This will provide the charge needed to transfer to the sampling capacitor within the processor.

Comment: Hi Kevin,
That's a simple solution.I will try it and report back to you.Is it also possible to reduce the potentiometer resistance by adding a resistor in parallel?

Comment: Hi Kevin, i am not sure on what pins you want me to connect the capacitors.Add a cap on each ground input of the pots?Between the GND of the STM32 and the GND of the pot?All pots share the same GND wire.

Comment: Adding a 0.1uF capacitor to ground at each input solved the problem thank you

Comment: @AlexTselikas - putting a resistor in parallel with the pot would not be very useful and would drastically alter the linearity of the angle to voltage law making it non-linear.