# STM32 A/D conversion: Vrefint channel value changes with external channel voltage

Tags: stm32, adc

I followed the instructions given on [this website](https://controllerstech.com/stm32-adc-multi-channel-without-dma/) to get A/D measurements from two channels on my STM32F303. I am using the internal "Vrefint" channel to extrapolate the VDDA power supply voltage, and an external channel on PA1.

As per the linked website, this is my measurement:

```
// poll for Vref (extrapolate VDDA)
ADC_Select_CH_vref();
HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc1);

if (HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc1,100) == HAL_OK) {
    ADCvalue_vref = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1);
}

HAL_ADC_Stop(&hadc1);

HAL_Delay(100);

// poll for external a/d channel
ADC_Select_CH_lux();
HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc1);

if (HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc1,100) == HAL_OK) {
    ADCvalue_lux = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1);
}

HAL_ADC_Stop(&hadc1);
```

The value of ADCvalue_vref stays within +-100 of VREFINT_CAL (the calibrated value stored in the chip's read-only memory) if the PA1 pin is left to float. The value of ADCvalue_lux in this case is consistently about 300 lower.

However, if PA1 is connected to VDD (approx 3.3 V), then the value of ADCvalue_lux nears 4095, but so does the value of ADCvalue_vref. Likewise, when connecting PA1 to GND, the value of ADCvalue_lux nears 0, but then so does the value of ADCvalue_vref.

What might I be doing wrong? Should I use both available AD converters instead?

I am considering that there is a related question here [Turning potentiometer changes other potentiometer's value(STM32)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/487674/turning-potentiometer-changes-other-potentiometers-valuestm32), but I currently cannot add a capacitor. I'll add to my question if I get the opportunity to try this.

---

Edit to add: Adding a 0.1 uF capacitor to GND has not made any difference on the external pin. I am now wondering whether the A/D measurement coming from the Vrefint channel is correct at all, or if it's measuring something else entirely. It seems too great of a coincidence that, if PA1 is left unconnected, I seem to get a proper value from the Vrefint channel.

Comment: For posterity: I solved this by using both available A/D converters. This works, but is wasteful. A solution would be nice, but my current application is fine as-is.